# Oracle insert replace double quote (") to &quot;

Tags: xml, oracle

I have a requirement to replace a big XML in Oracle DB but after insert, the double quote (") is inserted as **&quot:**. Below is the example.

Input XML `<Node>"Some text value here"</Node>`

Inserted XML `<Node>&quot;Some text value here&quot;</Node>` notice the &quot

Anyone tell me what's going on here? Is this Oracle default behavior? how to resolve this?

Note: I tried to insert using SQL Developer and got the same result.

Comment: Why do you want to modify this behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes this is normal behavior of xml.
Xml has five restricted characters:`&lt; (<), &amp; (&), &gt; (>), &quot; ("), and &apos; (')`.
And you do not have to worry about it.

Check this example.

`create table example( xml xmltype);`

`insert into example values ('<Node>"Some text value here"</Node>') ;`

`select t.xml from example t;` result is `<Node>&quot;Some text value here&quot;</Node>`

But if you do `select extractValue( t.xml,'//text()')  from example t ;` resutl is `"Some text value here"`

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work in case of the extract() function. I used extract() in aggregation and get those '&quot;' symbols.

Answer (score 1):

to resolve you can use regexp_replace:

```
SELECT regexp_replace(e.name, '\&'||'amp;', '&')
FROM element e
```

Comment: + for strategy of concatenating the value.  I needed to replace &quot; and SQL developer would parse the value and ask for a parameter.